# java SE 6 (1.6.0_29-b11-402) and SE 7 (1.7.0-ea-b218) extremely slow under os x lion (i7 2,5 GHz)

Tags: java, osx-lion

I am struggling with a vanilla install of java SE6 (Java for OS X Lion Update 1). It just takes ages to load even for simple and repeated output of its version.

```
$ time java -version
java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11-402-11M3527)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.4-b02-402, mixed mode)

real    0m5.129s
user    0m0.063s
sys     0m0.018s
```

Using OpenJDK 7 does not improve the situation:

```
$ time java -version
openjdk version "1.7.0-ea"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-ea-b218)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode)   

real    0m5.928s
user    0m0.054s
sys     0m0.015s
```

I am running OS X Lion, MBP 2,5 GHz quad i7, 8GB RAM, SSD. Speed is not an issue in other regions of the system (OS, Interface, Media, Ruby), so I am not thinking about a general hardware defect.

Has somebody encountered similar issues or knows anything I could check / try / verify?
I am grateful for any advice!

Comment: it has something to do with my library path for root or a clean user it works fast (by means of java)